# Duplicates in string - google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, duplicates, textjoin

I have a cell, (coming from an extracted DB) in Google sheets looking like this:

```
MOMO EL COCO LISTO EL SAFWAN MOMO EL COCO LISTO EL SAFWAN (Mister)
```

I tried with SPLIT, etc function to get the non duplicate entry:

- Remove the (Mister) at the end: =index(split(B2,"("),1)
- Get the valid part of the name (non duplicate) which should be

  MOMO EL COCO LISTO EL SAFWAN

I have not found a way to do this. Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(.+)\("), " "))))
```

[image: 0]